# "Lights Out" Automated Scheduled Batch Creation of Excel Workbook?

Tags: excel, unix, automation, batch-file, scheduler

Anybody have a good approach to automate the batch creation of custom-formatted Excel workbooks at a regularly scheduled time or after an event occurs (e.g., file created, table loaded)?

To make things even more interesting, let's further assume that the source data is in a relational database or Unix file, and the results need to be e-mailed or transmitted to a Unix web server. Thanks!

Comment: What language? What OS? What format is the input data?

Comment: What purpose are you using this for? Do you just want to be able to open the files in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

In fact this is not a question, but a series of questions. I can see the following distinct questions inside this one (assuming, that you are going to use a scripting language like perl or python or something similar):

- The task must be performed

  - At regular time intervals: use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)
  - After a predefined event: not much to say here, it depends on what exactly you want.
- The data has to be retrieved from:

  - from the database: use the bindings for your language for the specific database you are using (example: [python bindings for sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html))
  - from a file (what is a *Unix* file anyway?): depending on the format of the file you can get away by using [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)/[awk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) or write a parser in your scripting (or otherwise :P) language of choice.
- The data has to be *massaged* into an excel workbook. Well, I am not so sure, what you mean by "custom formatted", but the easiest way to create an excel workbook is, indeed, just dumping it to `.csv`, but you can go further and actually produce a "pseudo-xls", by using the following template and saving the resulting file as `.xls` (it actually works):

> ```
>  <table>
>  <tr>
>    <td>field0</td>
>    <td>field1</td>
>    ..
>    <td>fieldX</td>
>  </tr>
>  ... ad inf
>  </table>
> ```

- The resulting file has to be:

  - emailed: use the `mail` command, which usually points to the default mailer on your system (exim, sendmail, postfix)
  - "transmitted" to a web server, - I am assuming here, that this means "transfered to another machine, so that it can be made accessible via http(s)". In that case you can use ftp, sftp or [rsync](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) (my favourite).

Sorry for being extremely non-specific, but it is not easy to deduce *what exactly* you are trying to achieve from your question.

Comment: You can do a lot with html and excel (application/vnd.ms-excel) also xml (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742640/exporting-to-excel-the-simple-way-but-not-csv) see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150339/generating-an-excel-file-in-asp-net

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the fact, that there is a multitude of ways to generate `.xls` files, but since the questioner is not so sure what exactly he wants, I've decided to include the most straightforward "quick and dirty" way.

Comment: @shylent Apologies, I had voted up your answer and added the notes for the OP, I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can read `.csv` (comma-seperated variable) or `.tsv` (tab-seperated variable) files. It's 'trivial' to dump your output into a csv (just make sure you escape any commas or tabs in your input), and excel can then read that.

If you want to produce a .xls file, you'll have to find a library in your language of choice that implements handling of .xls files. For instance, if you're using python, there's [an entire mailing list](http://groups.google.com.au/group/python-excel) devoted to talking about doing this

Comment: True. But without knowing what the actual purpose is, it's hard to give a good answer..